# merge two arrays in angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays,I want to merge them into one array to bind the Data to the HTML form,this is what I did:

Controller:

```
$scope.modifierOuCreerArticle = function() {
    var index = this.row.rowIndex;

    $http.get("URL1")
    .success(function(datagetArticle) {
        $scope.finalOperationsList = datagetArticle.listElementGamme;
        var v = $scope.finalOperationsList[$scope.finalOperationsList.length-1].operationId;


        $scope.listOperationsById(v);
        $scope.listfinal=$scope.finalOperationsList.concat($scope.listOperationsById);

        $scope.finalOperationsList = $scope.listfinal;
    });

$scope.listOperationsById = function(id) {
    $http.get(URL2)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.listOperationsById = data;
        });
}
```

I want to merge the content of "finalOperationsList" array and "listOperationsById" array and send the content to my form with the "listfinal"

but I get this in console:

```
$scope.listfinal :[{ content of finalOperationsList},null]
```

so please how can I correct my code to get the all data coming from the merge of "finalOperationsList" and "listOperationsById" arrays
thanks for help

Comment: Jina, you appear to be missing the closing bracket (`}`) for `modifierOuCreerArticle`.

Comment: your final code should be: `$scope.listfinal = $scope.finalOperationsList.concat($scope.listOperationsById);`

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the concat JavaScript method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  numeric = [1, 2, 3];

var alphaNumeric = alpha.concat(numeric);

console.log(alphaNumeric); // Result: ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: yes Sir,I know that,but my problem is that I can't get the Data from the $scope.listOperationsById function ,how can I modify my code to get this data and merge it with the finalOperationsList array?

Comment: try this:
$scope.listOperationsById = function(id) {
    $http.get(URL2)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.listOperationsById = data;
            $scope.listfinal = $scope.finalOperationsList.concat(data)
        });
}

Answer (score 4):

Use conact function

```
var a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var b = ["5", "6", "7", "8"];
var c = a.concat(b);
```

**OR**

```
angular.extend(c, a, b);
```

Comment: @andreasonny83  that's not a problem  dude :)

Comment: thanks Sirs but using the concat method doesn't help me,I get always the data from the "$scope.finalOperationsList"

Answer (score 1):

You should use angular's $q.all : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

It'll allow you to easily handle all the data, when *both* of your async methods return